# VBA Formula creation uses the name of the Variable rather than the value

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Im trying to create a code which will allow me to pull the average of 6 rows from a sheet called 'Raw Data' and dump it into a cell in a different worksheet, and then pull the average of the next 6 rows from 'Raw Data' and so on.

E.G. average('RawData'! A1:A6) in a new sheet A1

then

average('Raw Data'! A7:A12) In new sheet A2

etc.

So far I have managed to make the code loop in a way that I want however Im having trouble writing the actual formula in new sheet A1 and A2.

so far I have tried:

```
        Dim address13 As String
        address13 = "'Raw Data'" & "!" & Cells(start_row, RPM1300).Address & ":" & _
        Cells(end_row, RPM1300).Address

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select

       '1300
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average(""" & address13 & """)"
```

However this returns the correct formula but with "" around it - rendering it useless.

I have also tried:

```
   Sheets("Raw Data").Select

   Dim address9 As Range

   Set address9 = Range(Cells(start_row, RPM900).Address(), Cells(end_row,      RPM900).Address())


   Sheets("New Sheet").Select

   rCell.Activate

   ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Select

   ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average(address9)"
```

However this just returns the name of the variable address9 in the formula rather than the actual range.

Note that RPM1300, RPM900, start_row, end_row and rCell are all variables in order for the code to loop and paste into the correct places.

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Comment: Just remove the extra quotes:  `"=Average(" & address13 & ")"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your line:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average(""" & address13 & """)"
```

With:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & address13 & ")"
```

**The reason**: the variable `address13` is already defined as a `String`, that's why you don't need the extra `"` inside the brackets.

### Code (use your first method:)

```
Dim address13 As String

address13 = "'Raw Data'!" & Cells(start_row, RPM1300).Address & ":" & _
Cells(end_row, RPM1300).Address

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & address13 & ")"
```

**Note**: Try avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell` , instead use referenced `Ranges` and `Worksheets`.

For instance, let's say you start from Cell A1, and you want this formula to be in Cell A5, you can use:

```
Range("A1").Offset(4, 0).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & address13 & ")"
```

Comment: So despite me trying every combination of quotation marks I could think of I'm obviously having a slow day because this solved it. Thanks a lot Shai!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bug in your version of Excel. Instead of

```
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average(""" & address13 & """)"
```

try using

```
    ActiveCell.Formula = '=Average("' & address13 & '")'
```

(single quotes around strings with double quotes and using only 1 double quote then).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't like that either, comes up with a compile error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average(""" & address13 & """)"
```

Try

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average("& chr(34) & address13 & chr(34) & ")"
```

At least here chr(34) returns the quotes you want. This may be tweaked if needed. Just change the number inside the ( )

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
Sub CellValue()
Dim adr As String
Dim sht As String
sht = "'Raw Data'"
adr = "A1:A3"
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & sht & "!" & adr & ")"
End Sub
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give you the same result and you'd be able to autofill it by dragging the cell handle.

> =AVERAGE(OFFSET('Raw Data'!$A$2,ROW(A1)*6-7,0,6,1))

[image]
Filling in both formulas

```
Sub FillFormulas()
    Const BASE_FORMULA = "=AVERAGE('Raw Data'!@Address)"
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim Formulas
    With Worksheets("Raw Data")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row / 6
    End With
    ReDim Formulas(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1)
    With Worksheets("New Sheet")
        For x = 1 To lastRow
            Formulas(x, 1) = Replace(BASE_FORMULA, "@Address", .Cells((x * 6) - 5, 1).Resize(6).Address)
        Next
        .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow).Formula = Formulas
        .Range("C1").Resize(lastRow).Formula = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET('Raw Data'!$A$2,ROW(A1)*6-7,0,6,1))"

    End With

End Sub
```